# solve "The Windows Modules Installer must be updated before you can install this package. 0x800f0823"

Tags: windows

Unable to install MSU package on Windows server 2008 R2.

Error message: "**The Windows Modules Installer must be updated before you can install this package. Please update the Windows Modules Installer on the computer, then retry Setup.**"

Error Code: 0x800f0823
OS: Windows Server 2008 R2

How to solve this error?

Comment: Did you seriously consider updating `The Windows Modules Installer`? What steps *have* you taken, and to what avail?

Comment: Yes, I was able to install the package after updating Servicing Stack Update as mentioned in this link .  https://www.ebugg-i.com/windows/solved-the-windows-modules-installer-must-be-updated-before-you-can-install-this-package/